# How can I ensure and confirm that the scipy package I installed has pythran optimized functions available?

Tags: python, pip, scipy, pythran

How can I ensure and confirm that the SciPy package I installed has pythran optimized functions available? I am installing python 3.9.5 from python software foundation website, using PyCharm IDE for package management that uses pip to set up packages.

Answer (score 0):

If you've used pip to install the SciPy 1.7.0 wheel from PyPI, it will have the Pythran modules included by default (the extensions can be excluded by setting the environment variable `SCIPY_USE_PYTHRAN=0` when building).

```
>>> import scipy.interpolate._rbfinterp_pythran
>>> help(scipy.interpolate._rbfinterp_pythran)
Help on module scipy.interpolate._rbfinterp_pythran in scipy.interpolate:

NAME
    scipy.interpolate._rbfinterp_pythran

DATA
    __pythran__ = ('0.9.11', '2021-06-19 21:59:20.760235', '3c30425550c454...

FILE
    ...\lib\site-packages\scipy\interpolate\_rbfinterp_pythran.cp39-win_amd64.pyd
```